# What to with reset pin when laying out Arduino PCB?

Tags: system-design

I'm designing a PCB with a standard arduino ATMEGA328 DIP IC. Do I need to make a connection to the reset pin?

Comment: You absolutely need one! What if you have to reset your processor but you can't detach from the power supply?

Answer (score 1):

["Atmel AVR042: AVR Hardware Design Considerations"](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_applicationnote_avr042.pdf)

[image: AVR reset connections]

Comment: +1 for the ref. “The reset line has an internal pull-up resistor, but if the environment is noisy it can be insufficient and reset can therefore occur sporadically.” So it seems one could possibly live without in “quiet” environments...

Comment: Certainly. None of my prototypes use the above circuit, but my final products do.

Comment: I don't get the diode however, if you only connect a button. Can noise really cause it to enter high-voltage-programming-mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do.  The pin needs to be pulled up to Vcc via a pullup resistor - typically 10KΩ.  Also, if you are using the Arduino bootloader and want to program via serial then this pin should be connected to your serial interface's DTR pin through a 100nF (typically) capacitor.  It is also often desirable to provide a reset button which switches this pin to ground.

You should examine the Arduino Uno's schematics and use them as a reference.